# $http service angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm utilising Angular's $http service in  controller to make an HTTP request to  web server to fetch the data in the app/phones/phones.json file.But the list of phones will not get displayed via index.html.

app/js/controllers.js:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });
  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
 }]);
```

///////////
index.html:

```
<html  ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Phone Gallery:{{query}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <!--Sidebar content-->
                Search:<input ng-model="query">
                Sort by:
                <select ng-model="orderProp">
                    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
                    <option value="age">Newest</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <!--Body content-->
                <ul class="phones">
                    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones| filter:query|orderBy:orderProp">
                        <span> {{phone.name}} </span>
                        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>


    <div style="padding:100px">
    Additional
    <p> Total number of phones:{{phones.length}}</p>
    <p>Hello,{{name}}!</p>

    <table>
        <tr><th>row number</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td><td>{{i + 1}}</td></tr> 

    </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////////

here's the json file:

```
[
{
    "age": 0, 
    "id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi", 
    "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg", 
    "name": "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi", 
    "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\r\n\r\nExperience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)."
}, 
{
    "age": 1, 
    "id": "motorola-xoom", 
    "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg", 
    "name": "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122", 
    "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\n\nExperience the future with MOTOROLA XOOM, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)."
}, 
{
    "age": 2, 
    "carrier": "AT&T", 
    "id": "motorola-atrix-4g", 
    "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-atrix-4g.0.jpg", 
    "name": "MOTOROLA ATRIX\u2122 4G", 
    "snippet": "MOTOROLA ATRIX 4G the world's most powerful smartphone."
}, 
{
    "age": 3, 
    "id": "dell-streak-7", 
    "imageUrl": "img/phones/dell-streak-7.0.jpg", 
    "name": "Dell Streak 7", 
    "snippet": "Introducing Dell\u2122 Streak 7. Share photos, videos and movies together. It\u2019s small enough to carry around, big enough to gather around."
}]
```

Comment: Your conclusion is based on?

Comment: $scope.phones = data.data; or show data format from server

Comment: Are you sure you get the `data` from the call?

Comment: I copied the code and it seems to show all the phones. can you check the console if it is getting all the files/jsons.

Comment: @Kop4Lyf how do I  check the console if it is getting all the files/jsons?

Comment: see network tab. it will come as red in console as well

Comment: The above code works fine in firefox but not google chrome.what could be the reason?

Comment: I checked in google chrome only :-). Are you putting the folder in some server like apache or directly running index.html file? chrome does not allow to access other files if you run it like that. Firefox allows that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/17K7bH7IQ1RgwY6JZMiN?p=preview

change you get call to which allows you to see why $get is not working

```
$http.get('phones.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.phones = response.data;
  },
  //failed $get call
  function(a, b, c) {
    alert("can't get data")
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that you have to allow loading of json files in your web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

I've had a similar problem and solved it with this.
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: In your web.config file, under your <system.webserver> tag. And make sure you have it included on your IIS server, create a new MIME type JSON, add Extension: .json and MIME type: application/json. I had a problem with loading .json files and solved it with this steps.